# How to save changed color of button on Recyclerview when scrolling to down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm build app display posts like facebook
and I using reyclerview vertical
when I click on like button is change to blue button and scroll to down
and back to up
the button is back to without any change 
how to stop this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use one class to save the state of a particular item in the view

```
public class Post {
    public boolean isLiked;
}
```

and in ViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post post = posts[position];
        if (post.isLiked) {
            //set color here
        } else {
            //remove color here
        }
        //change value of post.isLiked inside click listener
}
```